Azure Speech Service (v3.2): Poor speaker diarization quality with batch transcription + How to choose correct base model?
Current Issue

Using Azure Speech Service v3.2 with batch transcription
Speaker diarization fails to distinguish between male and female speakers
Previously worked well
Using mono audio file

Current Configuration

{
    "properties": {
        "diarizationEnabled": true,
        "wordLevelTimestampsEnabled": true,
        "displayFormWordLevelTimestampsEnabled": true,
        "channels": [0, 1],
        "diarization": {
            "speakers": {
                "minCount": 1,
                "maxCount": 25
            }
        }
    },
    "locale": "de-DE"
}

Current Model
Using base model: acf3c487-5d8c-4a4a-8241-f508cb5f2059 (German West Central)
Current code
import sys
import requests
import time
import ast
import os
import copy
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import swagger_client
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions


def transcribe_from_single_blob(self, uri, job_id, language, properties):
"""
Transcribe a single audio file located at `uri` using the settings specified in `properties`
using the base model for the specified locale.
"""

transcription_definition = swagger_client.Transcription(
    display_name=str(job_id),
    description='Transciption with Azure Base Model',
    locale=language,
    content_urls=[uri],
    properties=properties
) 

def transcribe(self, blob_uri, job_id, language):
logging.info("Starting transcription client...")

# configure API key authorization: subscription_key
configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = self.SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
configuration.host = f"https://{self.SERVICE_REGION}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.2"

properties = swagger_client.TranscriptionProperties()
properties.profanity_filter_mode = "None"  
properties.time_to_live = "PT48H"  
properties.punctuation_mode = "Automatic"
properties.word_level_timestamps_enabled = True
properties.display_form_word_level_timestamps_enabled = True


if self.number_speaker != 1:
    properties.diarization_enabled = True
    properties.diarization = swagger_client.DiarizationProperties(swagger_client.DiarizationSpeakersProperties(min_count=1, max_count=(25 if self.number_speaker == 0 else self.number_speaker)))
else:
    properties.diarization_enabled = False

# create the client object and authenticate
client = swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration)

# create an instance of the transcription api class
api =swagger_client.CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi(api_client=client)
transcription_definition = self.transcribe_from_single_blob(blob_uri, job_id, language, properties)
created_transcription, status, headers = api.transcriptions_create_with_http_info(transcription=transcription_definition) 

Questions
How can I improve the speaker diarization quality?
How do I choose the correct base model for German batch transcription?
What's the difference between regular base models and batch transcription models?

Configured proper diarization settings


Have you tried any code?

What do you mean? I'm using it with the Swagger client in Python.

Can you share your code in the question?

Yes. I added it


How can I improve the speaker diarization quality?


Check your mono audio file has high clarity and minimal background noise. Poor-quality audio impacts diarization.
Set the minCount and maxCount of speakers more tightly based on expected speaker counts. If the number of speakers is known in advance, set minCount equal to maxCount


How do I choose the correct base model for German batch transcription?

Use the German locale model (de-DE) designed for batch transcription, as specified in your configuration
Also, you can use the below code to list the Base Models for German (de-DE)
Code:
import requests

subscription_key = 'xxxxx'
region = 'xxx'  

# URL to get the base models
url = f'https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.2/models/base'

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    models = response.json()
   
    print("Full response:")
    print(models)
    
    # Now, attempt to extract and print models for German (de-DE)
    if 'values' in models:
        print("Available Base Models for German (de-DE):")
        for model in models['values']:
            if model.get('locale') == 'de-DE':
                print(f"Model: {model}")
            else:
                print("No matching model for de-DE in response")
    else:
        print("No 'values' field in the response")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)

Output:
{
  "self": "https://germanywestcentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.2/models/base/b12dd8ee-83be-4d51-8622-4708f079e3e8",
  "links": {
    "manifest": "https://germanywestcentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.2/models/base/b12dd8ee-83be-4d51-8622-4708f079e3e8/manifest"
  },
  "properties": {
    "deprecationDates": {
      "adaptationDateTime": "2021-07-15T00:00:00Z",
      "transcriptionDateTime": "2021-07-15T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "features": {
      "supportsTranscriptions": true,
      "supportsEndpoints": true,
      "supportsTranscriptionsOnSpeechContainers": false,
      "supportsAdaptationsWith": [
        "Language",
        "Acoustic",
        "Pronunciation",
        "OutputFormatting"
      ],
      "supportedOutputFormats": [
        "Display",
        "Lexical"
      ]
    },
    "chargeForAdaptation": false
  },
  "lastActionDateTime": "2021-09-27T11:00:32Z",
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-09-27T10:58:10Z",
  "locale": "de-DE",
  "displayName": "20190701 (v4.0.3 Unified)",
  "description": "de-DE base model (supports customization with audio)"
}


What's the difference between regular base models and batch transcription models?

Regular Base Models:

It is used for real-time transcription or streaming scenarios
It will handle small audio segments and not perform as well with long-form or noisy recordings.

Usefulness:
It will used for Live event transcriptio
Batch transcription models

It is designed for processing large audio files and are optimized for transcription of lengthy recordings, such as podcasts, meetings, or interviews
It will handle long duration audio files and complex scenarios like diarization and offer better accuracy for large datasets.

Usefulness: if your scenario is higher accuracy is needed, and some delay is acceptable and it is more scalable.
Reference:

Batch transcription overview - Speech service - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn
Base Models - List - REST API (Azure Azure AI Services) | Microsoft Learn

